# Postgresql event trigger on create database

Tags: postgresql

On the server side, I need to have a `.pg_service.conf` with an entry to every database on Postgresql. This `.pg_service.conf` is needed by QGIS Server to have access to all tables in all databases to render maps from tables with geometry columns.

**I want to update `.pg_service.conf` when new databases are added, renamed or removed.**

Currently, I have a cron job that runs on every minute and does a simple query:

```sql
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false and datname != 'postgres'
```

As far I can see in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html), there is no event trigger for `CREATE DATABASE`.

Is it possible to have some kind of event on Postgresql that can be fired on database related DDL statements?

Comment: From [Event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html): 'An event trigger fires whenever the event with which it is associated occurs in the database in which it is defined.  ... As an exception, however, this event does not occur for DDL commands targeting shared objects — databases, roles, and tablespaces — or for commands targeting event triggers themselves. The event trigger mechanism does not support these object types. ' So no.

Comment: The expectations were already low. Thanks @AdrianKlaver for being so clear.

Comment: i wonder if it is possible to put INSERT trigger on pg_database table ...