# Allow user to create specific Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add several users to a Postgres database. They should be able to do anything to any object they own.

The catch is that they can't start with any owned objects. They should be able to create a single database (preferably named after them) themselves.

Once they have created a database, they should never be able to create another one -- even if the first one gets deleted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe create a function in the maintenance database that lets them create their database and which prevents running the function again?

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately I can't control how they create the database (e.g. force them to use the function). But perhaps you know of a way to have a function be triggered when they create a database that then removed the permission?

Comment: Yes you do have that control: "*To create a database, you must be a superuser or have the special `CREATEDB` privilege.*" ([`CREATE DATABASE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)). Assuming they don't have either privilege, they'll have no other way than your function.

Comment: "*a way to have a function be triggered when they create a database*" - I thought about that as well, but [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/event-triggers.html)   "*are global to a particular database*" so I doubt they can trigger on `CREATE DATABASE`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814937/postgresql-event-trigger-on-create-database

Comment: @Bergi I don't have the control over the user because it will be run by existing, 3rd-party software using the user. I can't make the software use my new function.

Comment: So what exactly does the software do? If you cannot control it (or write an adapter that does), you probably also cannot control the names of the databases these users create.